# 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We were unable to automatically populate your Visual Studio Team Services accounts.

[image]

The following error was encountered:

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Microsoft Azure Tools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: `We were unable to automatically populate your Visual Studio Team Services accounts`
Did you mean that when you did some operations to VSTS, then you got the error. Please provide more detailed scenario or step about this issue. Also, what is the version of Azure Storage Emulator and Microsoft Azure SDK installed in your environment?

Comment: See related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450542/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-azure-store-emulator-controller-vers

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above, but still get error when try to install storage emulator 4.6 :

```
> === Logging started: 11/1/2017  13:25:03 ===
Action start 13:25:03: INSTALL.
Action start 13:25:03: AppSearch.
Action ended 13:25:03: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 13:25:03: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 13:25:03: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 13:25:03: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: CostInitialize.
Action ended 13:25:03: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: FileCost.
Action ended 13:25:03: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: SetREINSTALLMODE.
Action ended 13:25:03: SetREINSTALLMODE. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: CostFinalize.
Action ended 13:25:03: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: SetCommandForRunInitialize.
Action ended 13:25:03: SetCommandForRunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: InstallValidate.
Action ended 13:25:03: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:03: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 13:25:04: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 13:25:04: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 13:25:04: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 13:25:04: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RemoveRegistryValues.
Action ended 13:25:04: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RemoveShortcuts.
Action ended 13:25:04: RemoveShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 13:25:04: RemoveFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: InstallFiles.
Action ended 13:25:04: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RunInitialize.
Action ended 13:25:04: RunInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: CreateShortcuts.
Action ended 13:25:04: CreateShortcuts. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: WriteRegistryValues.
Action ended 13:25:04: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RegisterUser.
Action ended 13:25:04: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 13:25:04: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 13:25:04: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: PublishProduct.
Action ended 13:25:04: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 13:25:04: InstallFinalize.
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.6.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  Error: No available SQL Instance was found.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff6: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff6: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 13:25:04: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 13:25:04: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {CF5CD495-AEDE-42DA-B7CF-A70D398D4E6A}
Property(S): RunInitialize = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
Property(S): DOTNET4FULL = 4.6.01055
Property(S): LOCALDB11INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): LOCALDB12INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): LOCALDB13INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): TARGETDIR = D:\
Property(S): StorageEmulatorMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): STORAGEEMUDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(S): REINSTALLMODE = amus
Property(S): AzureMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Azure\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): AZUREDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\
Property(S): MICROSOFTSDKSDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.4.6.VS2015\87D0206176A522CAE276152FD4B361ACE3D4F258\
Property(S): MSIRMSHUTDOWN = 1
Property(S): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
Property(S): ProductCode = {CE32346F-023F-4259-BE16-D601AFECFFEE}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.6
Property(S): ProductVersion = 4.6.16364.1446
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERVERSIONDETECTED;OLDEMULATORPACKAGEDETECTED;OLDERVERSIONDETECTED
Property(S): WixPdbPath = X:\bt\760165\repo\src\XFE\DevelopmentStorage\BuildPackages\40BuildMsi\SetupPackage\obj\amd64\en-us\MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.wixpdb
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {073B905A-DECD-4DDC-B033-577329B2A084}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\Jalal\Downloads
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 3876
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 601
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 601
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 7601
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 1
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\Jalal\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 16208
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 25999
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = jalal
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-449103266-2938114754-3326020072-1114
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = JALAL-PC
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 22
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 13:25:04
Property(S): Date = 1/11/2017
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.6.1087.0
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7601.17514
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = Jalal
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\14ab42.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.4.6.VS2015\87D0206176A522CAE276152FD4B361ACE3D4F258\MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = D:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\Jalal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.4.6.VS2015\87D0206176A522CAE276152FD4B361ACE3D4F258\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {CE32346F-023F-4259-BE16-D601AFECFFEE}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (EC:A0) [13:25:04:820]: Product: Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.6 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (EC:A0) [13:25:04:820]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v4.6. Product Version: 4.6.16364.1446. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

=== Logging stopped: 11/1/2017  13:25:04 ===
```

---

**Solution:**

Finally, it works :)

I solved it by `stop`, `delete`, then `restart sqllocaldb`. But all posts I read mentioned just how to do that with `sqllocaldb`. In my case, i found that I have 2 instances, `sqllocaldb`, and `MSSQLLocaldb`. So it works after I did the steps with `MSSQLLocaldb`.

1. `sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocaldb`
2. `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocaldb`
3. Delete `WAStorageEmulatorDb34.mdf` and `WAStorageEmulatorDb34_log.ldf` ( in my case ) from `C:\Users\[UserName]`
4. `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocaldb`

Then try to install again the storage emulator and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral..."

I am running Azure SDK tools 2.9.6 (latest, I believe it comes with storage emulator 4.5). All was running fine. When I updated to Windows Azure Storage Client library 8.0.0 and ran my project, I got an exception that I need latest emulator 4.6.
I downloaded and installed it and now above errors shows when i try to click inside Server Explorer on Storage/development node

Tried also steps above from Jahan, unfortunately did not work for me. I think this works in cases emulator was not properly installed.

Seems to me problem is related to emulator 4.6 version, but I can easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator from control panel and make sure if you have LocalDb installed or not by running this command

```
> sqllocaldb info
```

Now, if you have it installed then, run the following commands

```
> sqllocaldb stop v11.0     --(v11.0 in my case)
> sqllocaldb delete v11.0   --(v11.0 in my case)
> sqllocaldb create v11.0   --(v11.0 in my case)
```

Then, go to C:\Users(Your User Name) and delete all the .mdf and .ldf files named with AzureStorageEmulatorDB_xx

Reinstall Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator.

(At least these steps helped me to solve the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Unistall and reinstall the Azure Storage Emulator, worked for me with ver 4.6.0.0.