# Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Azure.Store.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0"

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm getting this message after upgrading to Azure Storage Emulator 4.6 and v8.0.0 of WindowsAzure.Storage.

I have spent two days trying to get this to work including reformatting and installing all dev tools on two machines. This has happened with THREE previous Microsoft releases, either the Azure SDK, or the emulator or some combination of the two is broken.

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361602/microsoft-azure-storage-emulator-controller-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutral.

Comment: I have, same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get things working with the previous version (again) with the following steps:

1. Uninstalled v4.6 of the Storage Emulator.
2. Deleted database files (mdf, ldf) under C:\Users\\
3. Downloaded and installed v4.5 Storage Emulator.
4. Reverted WindowsAzure.Storage to v7.2.1 (via NuGet)
5. Did a search for "8.0.0" in the solution to identify any remaining binding redirects that use v8.0.0 of WindowsAzure.Storage. Delete these if any are found.

This got me up and running again until there is a proper solution to use the latest version of the above libraries.